# UML database schema based on the creteria

Tags: schema

**I have the following requirements to design a database schema (brief):**

- A Graphic Designer (we will call them designer) gets a call from a client with a new job to design a logo.
- The designer logs-in to JobBook and registers the job by job name, description and a client.
- The designer can assign an existing client to a job, or register a new client.
- Registering a client means imputing a basic billing information (name, address, VAT number, telephone, email).
- Every time the designer works on a job, they open the JobBook and note down the date and hours worked on the specific job. They should also note down the type of task they have been doing (e.g. logo colour iteration).
- Each job has a status: open, invoiced or paid. Once the job is complete, the designer changes the status from open to invoiced. The JobBook now has all the required information to issue an invoice.
- Once the job is paid, the designer changes the status form invoiced to paid. Each status change should have a timestamp.

*Based on the above, I need to design schema in form of UML.*

### This is what I have so far:

#### Versions 1:

[image: Version 1]

In this diagram I assume that there can be more designers working with one client and the other way around. So that job can be split into different parts (for example, one job can be separated into 1. design logo, 2. design web-design, 3. design banner and etc). This is why I have such database schema. Also another reason for me doing this schema is because of the future expansion of the database, because currently, this is not considered by the brief (above).

#### Versions 2:

[image: Version 2]
This version just allows just one designer working with one client and not splitting of the job is considered in this version.

## Question

Would you consider version 1 or version 2 to be correct database schema? If not, please help me to defined correct solution for the requirements mentioned above.

PS. This is homework (not actual project, etc).